# Генерация кода на C# из .proto файла

Tags: c#, grpc

Подскажите пожалуйста как сгенерировать код из файла .proto в классы и методы на C#. Находил информацию о том что необходимы какие то NuGet пакеты, а затем что то прописать в консоли. Но конкретной инструкции не нашел.
Появляется ошибка Строка    Состояние подавления
protoc-gen-grpc: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: 1) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/grpc/ 2) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms

Comment: не нашел решение проблемы там.

Comment: Вы установили пакет Grpc.Tools, вы добавили proto-файлы, как там описано? Вот ещё ссылка: [gRPC services with C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Не забудьте сбилдить проект после этого.

Comment: Можете использовать protoc из командной строки. [Generating Your Classes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#generating). Устанавливайте пакет и действуйте по инструкции. [C# Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated)

Comment: protoc : Имя "protoc" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.

Comment: Я установил пакеты Grpc.Tools, Google.Protobuf. Но все равно не может найти путь к чему то. C:\Users\Никита\source\repos\Billing\Billing\--grpc_out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все я разобрался. Помоему protoc не распознает кириллицу, поэтому путь к файлу такой как:

```
C:\Users\Никита\source\repos\Billing\Billing\
```

он не мог распознать, и видел как: и выводил ошибку что такого пути не найдено

```
C:\Users\═шъшЄр\source\repos\Billing\Billing\
```

Поэтому я просто сменил имя системной папки: (поковырявшись в настройках Windows)

```
C:\Users\Nik\source\repos\Billing\Billing\
```

Спасибо всем. Осталось разобраться как теперь написать саму логику сервиса)

Comment: А, да, бывает такая проблема с некоторыми программами, действительно